# Facebook Error Code 100 - Invalid Parameter for reading posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I received an email notification from Facebook a few days ago reporting an error.

"In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method GET /posts resulted in errors."

- Error Code   100
- Error Description    Invalid parameter
- Error Count  3771

Not sure what caused this error. I've tested the API call in both my local dev environment and on the live production environment and it appears to load the data just fine. I just want to make sure there isn't an underlying problem I need to address.

I'm using Facebook's PHP library to get an access token and then I make this call with Wordpress' wp_remote_get function:

```
$data = wp_remote_get("https://graph.facebook.com/{$page_name}/posts?access_token={$access_token}", array('sslverify' => false));
```